# Need help using the file system

Tags: java, swing, exception

I'm trying to load an image onto a JPanel. I define an Image as this:

```
    Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("~/Desktop/Example.png"));
```

This line returns the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at Background.<init>(Background.java:16)
```

(This is at line 16 of my code)

Comment: Java doesn't know what `~` means.

Comment: Is this image supplied by your app. or the end user?

Answer (score 7):

The tilde character `~` is expanded by a shell so needs to be replaced to be used in Java. You could do

```
Image image = 
    ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Example.png"));
```